# PL/SQL Waterfall Bridge Chart

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a waterfall charts in Oracle Apex 20.1.

In my chart I want to display a bar chart for every month and the deltas for each month. Furthermore, the deltas of each month should only affect the corrsponding month (bar in chart). For instance, the deltas for the month april only are applied for this month. For may the computation starts from the beginning.

I hope the following explanation helps more to tackle the problem:

- In my application I have one modal dialog page where everytime a user can define a new project with the delta value (i.e., something like project value increaes or decreases) with a due date.
- One Project can have multiple values based on its progress. Meaning the number of deltas is unknown and thus should be dynamic in the chart
- Based on the ascending due dates per month the delta progress should be computed for every month. Every delta should be a new starting proint for further computation within the month range
- The month and its deltas are not connected and thus the computation should not be ongoing
- The value for the months is being given afterwards and is applied for every delta within the month. So April with the value 200 could have 5 deltas, while May with the value 100 could have only two for instance

With help the following chart is being displayed with one delta and ongoing computation:

```
    with PLAN_PROJECT (mon, val, delta_one, delta_two, delta_three, dir as (
 select 'Month 1' mon, 150 val, 30 delta_one, -15 delta_two, 0 delta_three, 0 dir from dual union all
 select 'Month 2' mon, 100 val, -20 delta_one, 45 delta_two, 0 delta_three, 0 dir from dual union all
 select 'Month 3' mon, 120 val, 10 delta_one, 20 delta_two, -5 delta_three, 0 dir from dual
)
select mon, val, delta_one, delta_two, delta_three, dir from PLAN_PROJECT union all
 select * from(
  select 'Delta '||row_number() over(order by mon),
      least( val, lead(val,1) over(order by mon)) lo,
      greatest( val, lead(val,1) over(order by mon)) hi, 
      sign(lead(val,1) over(order by mon)- val ) dir
case sign (lead (hi, 1) over (order by to_date(mon,'MM / YYYY')) - hi )
  when -1 then '#d20000' 
  when  1 then '#3db014' 
  when  0 then '#92A2BD'
end
  from PLAN_PROJECT
 ) where val is not null
)
order by mon desc
```

Here is how the chart should look like:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Kind regards.